# Tightly Encapsulated Class

Tags: java

This is my homework question : 
Which among the following classes is NOT Tightly Encapsulated?

```
class A
{
    private int x;
}
class B
{
    private int x;
    public void setX(int x)
    {
        this.x=x;
    }
    public int getX()
    {
        return x;
    }
}
class C
{
    private int x;
    private void setX(int x)
    {
        this.x=x;
    }
    private int getX()
    {
        return x;
    }
}
```

I spent some time searching on coderanch but was not able to get the required stuff. Can anyone please help me?

What I think is Class C is not tightly encapsulated;because the methods are private. And about class A what I feel is it is not encapsulated only. Because basic definition of encapsulation says that "You must hide your members and provide to the class user methods that behave the way you want." Now the class A has no accessor-mutator methods. So A should not be considered encapsulated. I am not sure but. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: This probably won't help you, but the question is posed (presumably by your instructors) in an absurdly abstract way. A class is tightly encapsulated when it only exposes the interface its clients need. It's pretty much impossible to say meaningfully without knowing the purpose of a given class.

Answer (score 5):

How is "tight encapsulation" defined in your class?  There is no academia or industry-wide definition of this as far as I can tell from a Google search.

I could argue that each class is well-encapsulated or each is poorly encapsulated.  Why is the client exposed to the name of the private variable X?  Seems unfortunate.  Why does class A not expose any functionality?  Is it "correct" for C to only expose a getter in the domain in which it should be used?

This question just misrepresents the concept of encapsulation.  You can't run code through an "encapsulation verifier" routine.  It's a human design decision in which you say that that which is exposed ought to be and that which isn't shouldn't be.  Fundamentally, this generally requires data to be private, but whether a method should be public or private depends entirely on what it actually means and is doing.

Answer (score 2):

You're exactly right.  Both Class A and Class C are not tightly encapsulated because tight encapsulation implies private fields paired with public getters and setters.

Comment: Now I am confused... Because I have 4 options :
A : Class A
B : Class B
C : Class C
D : None of above

Comment: Direct access to your internals implies encapsulation?

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of encapsulation is correct. But I think you are straying a little bit.

Encapsulation means you don't let others have direct access to your internals.  You expose user functionality and you manage your own internals.

So if I am a bank account - I have a private field called total.  I don't let users directly set my total.  Instead, I expose withdraw(double amt) and deposit(double amt) and I manage total as needed.

Don't get hung up on A only having a private member.  Consider these class fragments - like the user functionality is not shown and try answering again.

Comment: Actually this question is asked in a recruitment aptitude test with 4 options : 
class A,B,C or None. Out of them, only one is correct. So what is the most correct answer?

Comment: @user1500024 Out of those options? I'd say None because `B` exposes all its internals, and `A` and `C` expose nothing and are therefore useless. That said there's an argument to be made for answering "`B`" (because while it exposes `x` it at least controls access to it); just as there's an argument to be made for `A` and `C` since they don't expose `x` at all. It's just a ridiculously vague question.

Comment: I totally agree... I CURSE the person who has designed such a question.

Answer (score 1):

A class is said to be tightly encapsulated if and only if, all the data members(variables) of that class is declared as private.

if class has all variables declared as private and if it's inherited by other class which too has all private data members, then the later one is also said to be tightly encapsulated class.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the necessity of public accessors is mentioned in the definition of encapsulation because it simply makes sense, and for no other reason. So I'd say that tightly encapsulated class is a class that hides its members, preventing direct access to them by objects of other classes. That is all. I'd go with `None`, as all of these classes are encapsulated even if two of them don't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here class B will be tightly encapsulated because as per the definition "if a class is declared with private variables & public properties,it is said to be tightly  encapsulation
"

Answer (score 0):

All your above classes are tightly encapsulated.

A class is said to be tightly encapsulated if and only if, all the data members declared as private. Here we should not worry about whether public accessors or mutators is present or not.

Answer (score 0):

All the three classes described by you are tightly Encapsulated .

If a class is having only private variables and no other public variables then a class is said to be tightly encapsulated class.

It does not depend on the getter or setter methods.

We need to have getter and Setters as we need create variables so that we can use them in other class or functions .

So irrespective of the public getter and setter method all the three class are Tightly encapsulated .

Answer (score 0):

tightly Encapsulated class mean that all member variable declared as private so all classes are tightly Encapsulated 
NB if a parent class contain one member variable that is defined as not private your child class will not be tightly encapsulated

Answer (score 0):

All the classes here are tightly encapsulated as each and every variable is declared as private and we are not required to check whether the corresponding getter and setter methods are declared as public or not.

Answer (score 0):

"Tightly Encapsulated" classes follows only one rule, all the members (variables) are "private" inside a class, you can say "Tightly Encapsulated" class.
because "Tightly Encapsulated" concept does not depends on [getter,setter and their access modifier].

**in other words**

### All the **members** of class should be **private** that's it.

Answer (score -1):

A class is said to be "tightly encapsulated" if and only if every variable is declared as private.(irrespective if they contain *getter* or *setter* methods or not.

In your example **All** the three classes are tightly encapsulated since each class has every variable as private.

Answer (score -2):

These all classes are tightly encapsulated classes. All the instance variables should be private in a tightly encapsulated class. It doesn't care about whether the methods have any access modifier ( default, private, protected & public ).

Comment: Clarify your question a little better please.

Answer (score -2):

Every Java class by default Encapsulated class only, when we say the it is tightly encapsulated if and only if Every variable present in that class is private such type of class is called tightly encapsulated class.

For your question Ans: No class there.

Note: All class Tightly Encapsulated.

Comment: This answer is an nth duplicate of several other answers.